# Suppressor Class only working in notebook block and not in command line

Tags: python, decorator, suppress-warnings, rdkit, error-suppression

This is the class I am using as my supressor

```
import sys
import traceback
import warnings
from rdkit import RDLogger
from rdkit import Chem

class Suppressor:
    def __init__(self, log_file):
        self.log_file = log_file
        self.stdout = sys.stdout
        self.stderr = sys.stderr

    def __enter__(self):
        sys.stdout = self
        sys.stderr = self

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, value, tb):
        sys.stdout = self.stdout
        sys.stderr = self.stderr
        if exception_type is not None:
            raise Exception(f"Got exception: {exception_type} {value} {traceback}")

    def write(self, x):
        with open(self.log_file, "a") as log:
            log.write(x)
```

And this is how I'm using it.

```
with Suppressor("error.log"):
    Chem.MolFromSmiles('CO(C)C')
```

I have noticed that it works fine in notebook block, it does suppress and logs the output of `Chem.MolFromSmiles('CO(C)C')`.

But when I run a script that uses the suppressor in command line it does not suppress nor log the output of `Chem.MolFromSmiles('CO(C)C')`. However, it still suppress the output prints.

I tried it with different functions that raises errors and it works fine

Comment: Sounds like `Chem.MolFromSmiles()` is not writing to `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr` when running that way.

Comment: It might be writing directly to `/dev/tty`.